# Searching through a list of text files for the correct user and their information in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm very new to Python and I am making a simple program, which starts off with a menu. One of the options, once selected, will ask the user to enter a username. Once a username is entered, the program will search through a list of text files in that directory (Each user will have their own text file, potentially named after them so that when the username is entered, it finds that user) until it finds the right user, and displays their information in the program.

So the output would be like this
Enter the username: ProPlayer27 (Searching through a list of text files in the same directory for this username)
Result found - Proplayer27 + all of the information from that specific text file

I am really unsure of how to do this, I have tried various methods but with little to no success.

I would really appreciate any help I can get!

I understand that in order for all of the text files to be read in the first place, os.listdir needs to be used, so I am using that as a place to start. I have tried to divide it into 3 steps:

Take the input from the user

Search the text files for the user's input

Once the text file has been found, display it onto the program.

I have little to nothing to show, but I know that multiple text files in a directory can be found like this:

```
        for file in os.listdir("D:\Test"):
            if file.endswith(".txt"):
                print(os.path.join("Test", file))
```

Comment: Would you kindly settle on a question or at least on what you want? If you know what the name of the file is, just `open` it. If you don't know what the name is, `os.walk` for it, though you have given no indication how you recognize the right file if not by name

Comment: I was thinking that the user would prompted to "Search" for a username. When the username is inputted, it will search through all of the text files for that username, and then will display the text file that has that username in it.

Answer (score 1):

The following will do what you want using tkinter.

```
import tkinter as tk
import os
from pathlib import Path


def find_info():
    data = user_input.get() #gets the user input in the entry field
    entry.delete(0, tk.END) #delete the input after button pressed
    nothing = '' #  used ensure nothing happens if the entry is blank
    folder = "test data" # name of the folder where the text files exist
    connected = os.path.join(folder, data + ".txt") # joins the input for search
    record = Path(connected) # used for readability to check its existance
    lines_read = [] # empty list to store the data you will read

    if data != nothing: # make sure the entry was not left blank
        if record.exists(): # checks if the record infact exists
            with open(connected, "r") as x: # open and read the text file 
                for every_line in x.read().split("{}"): # list/string handling
                    if every_line not in lines_read: # check against empty list
                        lines_read.append(every_line) # writes the content to the list
                        result = "".join(lines_read) # format and join
                        check_label["text"] = result # display resutls on the check_label
                    
        

 
root = tk.Tk() 
root.geometry("400x200")
root.resizable(False, False)
root.title("Sample Program")

user_input = tk.StringVar()
entry = tk.Entry(root, text=user_input, width=20)
entry.pack()

button = tk.Button(root, text="Find Entry", command=lambda: find_info())
button.pack()

check_label = tk.Label(root, font="Times 12")
check_label.pack()

root.mainloop()
```